# Placing HTTP address in javascript variable for json parsing

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, variables

If I am to have this external json file:

```
{
"http://example.org/about" :
    {
        "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title" : [{"value" : "annas homepage" , "type" : "literal"}]
    }
}
```

and this external jquery script that fetches title of the book inside json file:

```
var a = 'http://example.org/about'
var b = 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title'

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#trigger").click(function(event) {
    $.getJSON('rdfjson.json', function(json) {
      $('#meta').html('Title: ' + json.a.b[0].value);
    });
  });
});
```

and this HTML code:

```
<p>Click on the button to fetch data from json structure:</p>
<div id="meta">
This text will be overwritten.
</div>
<input type="button" id="trigger" value="Load Data" />
```

Why wouldn't it work? When I use normal strings inside json document and script, it works OK.

Also, I don't understand how could I iterate through the whole json file if it is, for example, more complex or elements have long vectors containing data etc etc..

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're looking for an object member **named** `a`, rather than an object member whose name is the **value stored in the variable "a"**.

Instead of using "**dot notation**", use **"square bracket notation**"

```
$('#meta').html('Title: ' + json[a][b][0].value);
```

For more information, see here: http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/

**Edit:**

If the JSON structure varies like so:

1. Version One:

   ```
   {
       "http://example.org/about" :
       {
           "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title" : [{"value" : "annas homepage" , "type" : "literal"}]
       }
   }
   ```
2. Version Two:

   ```
   {
       "http://somewhereelse.com/something" :
       {
           "http://anotherplace.org/dc/blah-blah-blah/title" : [{"value" : "annas homepage" , "type" : "literal"}]
       }
   }
   ```

**e.g. there is always one object, which has one member which has one member**

... and you need to target it:

```
$.getJSON('rdfjson.json', function(obj) {
  for (var x in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
         var obj2 = obj[x];

         for (var x in obj2) {
            if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
                $('#meta').html('Title: ' + obj2[x][0].value);
            }
         }
      }
  }
});
```

You can of course add conditionals within the `for` loops if you know a little bit more information about the path you need to traverse:

```
$.getJSON('rdfjson.json', function(obj) {
  for (var x in obj) {
      // if you know you're looking for a key that begins with "http://"
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x) && x.indexOf("http://") === 0) { 
         var obj2 = obj[x];

         for (var x in obj2) {
            // Check that the value is an array of at least length 1, and whose 1st value has the property "value".
            if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(x) && obj2[x] instanceof Array && obj2[x].length > 0 && obj2[x][0].value) { 
                $('#meta').html('Title: ' + obj2[x][0].value);
            }
         }
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: +1 for detailing the explanation, instead of just giving the answer.

Comment: A little side question, is there a way to get the subject and predicate name of the json structure instead of typing it in the script manually and give it to variables a and b? I would need this if the json file is changing dynamically, for example.

Comment: @3mpetri: I'm not sure what you mean... can you try explain it another way/ give an example? The `json` part of `json[a][b][0].value` is decided by the variable name in the callback function for `getJSON`... it's independent of the JSON structure returned. Regardless of the layout of the JSON structure returned, `json` will always point to the root element... you then change **a** and **b** to refer to the members of the object you want.

Comment: Sure, the problem is changing the **a** and **b** variables. I'm fetching various json files depending on play time of the video ([link]http://b-webdesign.com/multilab/Test05/[link] - webm format video), so if I want to fetch a value, I need to change path to it according to what cue that outputs json file is active at given time. Messed up.

Comment: @3mpetri: You can pass the `a` and `b` variables into the `handleCue` function? See http://jsfiddle.net/BKjxX/ to see what I mean. Hope this makes sense :(. If not, can you say how you're planning to calculate `a` and `b`?

Comment: Thanks but the real problem is to _get_ the value of **a** and **b** from the json file, not only to assign them. Assignment must be automatic, and the values in json file are unpredictably dynamic - the paths change over time.

Comment: @3mpetri: I've updated my answer which I ***think*** answers you're question. If I'm still not understanding you correctly can you post some sample JSON responses, indicating **what** you're trying to target in each of them, and what parts of the JSON responses remain the same, and which parts change?

Comment: You got it perfect, thank you for your time and comprehensive answer! Works good with your idea, I used two each() methods and compared keys with part of an url.

http://b-webdesign.com/multilab/Ver2.1/

Comment: @3mpetri: Glad to hear :). Nice styling on the webpage btw!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use square bracket notation:

```
json[a][b][0].value
```

which will allow you to select properties using variables (which you *cannot* do with dot notation).

See http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#meta').html('Title: ' + json.a.b[0].value);
```

should be

```
  $('#meta').html('Title: ' + json[a][b][0].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the square brackets like sp:

```
json[a][b][0].value
```

Small test case here: http://jsfiddle.net/sSbtq/